# 422 (Unprocessable Entity) error

Tags: reactjs, http, post, loopbackjs

I am trying to pass an object called Questions which  has 3 properties. First and third properties are of type string and the second one is of type boolean. For example: `{"description: "What is ecommerce" , "requireMeeting": true, "expID": "1234"}`

When i try to send a post request through the front end i get the following error. (However when i add a new object via loopback explorer it works fine)

```
 Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 422 (Unprocessable Entity)
```

Here is the addQues function which sends a new object to the database

```
   addQues(newQues) {
    console.log(newQues);
    axios.request({
      method: 'Post',
      url: 'http://localhost:3001/api/Questions',
      data: newQues
    }).then(response => {
    }).catch(err => console.log(err));
  }
```

And this is the code of onSubmit function which passes the object to be added to the addQues

```
      onSubmit(e) {
    const newQues = {
      description: this.state.description,
      requireMeeting: this.state.requireMeeting,
      expID: this.state.expID
    };
    this.addQues(newQues);
    e.preventDefault();
}
```

and here is the full code

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import axios from 'axios';
import '../Styles.scss';

class Questions extends Component {
  addQues(newQues) {
    console.log(newQues);
    axios.request({
      method: 'Post',
      url: 'http://localhost:3001/api/Questions',
      data: newQues
    }).then(response => {
    }).catch(err => console.log(err));
  }
  constructor() {
    super();
    // this.onChange = this.onChange.bind(this);
    this.onDescriptionChange = this.onDescriptionChange.bind(this);
    this.onExpIdChange = this.onExpIdChange.bind(this);
    this.onIsmeetingChange = this.onIsmeetingChange.bind(this);
    this.state = {
      description: '',
      requireMeeting: false,
      expID: ''
    };
  }
  onExpIdChange(e) {
    this.setState({
      expID: e.target.value
    });
  }
  onDescriptionChange(e) {
    this.setState({
      description: e.target.value
    });
  }
  onIsmeetingChange(e) {
    this.setState({
      requireMeeting: true
      // document.getElementById("checkbox").checked = true;
    });
  }
  onSubmit(e) {
    const newQues = {
      description: this.state.description,
      requireMeeting: this.state.requireMeeting,
      expID: this.state.expID
    };
    this.addQues(newQues);
    e.preventDefault();
  }
  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        <br/>
        <h1> DO NOT HESISTATE TO ASK OUR EXPERTS </h1>
        <form onSubmit={this.onSubmit.bind(this)}>
          <div className="input-field">
            <label htmlFor="description"> Description </label>
            <textarea rows="10" cols="100" name="description" onChange={this.onDescriptionChange} />
          </div>
          <div className="input-field">
            <input type="text" name="expID" onChange={this.onExpIdChange} />
            <label htmlFor="name"> expID </label>
          </div>
          <div className="checkbox">
            <label>
              <input type="checkbox" name="requireMeeting"
                onClick={this.onIsmeetingChange} />Meeting
            </label>
          </div>
          <input type ="submit" value="ASK" className="btn" />
        </form>
      </div>
    );
  }
}
export default Questions;
```

Comment: You said "put" request but your code shows "post" - you meant post, right?

Comment: oh yes post @RaymondCamden

Comment: If you look at your browser dev tools, can you confirm the question data is correctly being passed in the body of the form post?

Comment: You may give a try with `data: JSON.stringify(newQues)`

Answer (score -2):

As http does not support boolean, its better to avoid boolean in POST/PUT body.. instead you can send 0 and 1 as false ,true and handle accordingly. sending 0 and 1 is a more compatible format for transferring boolean values via HTTP.

Comment: I don't believe this is correct - it is valid JSON which can be sent over the wire just fine.

Comment: This is blatantly wrong. Can you clarify what do you mean by: `http does not support boolean, its better to avoid boolean in POST/PUT`